# How to do build eas ios auth?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I have the problem with eas ios build in latest eas-cli version 3.7. When I try make a build the login authentication has the follow problem:

```
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
    Error: Apple Service Error -36607. Unable to sign you in to your Apple ID. Try again later. <a target="_blank" 
    href="https://support.apple.com/kb/HT212522 ">Learn more.<span class="sr-only"> Opens in a new window.</span></a>
```

At the same time that begin the build, the window`s mac authorization popup in the screen, but the build reports the problem in the same time and the authentication fails. I try several times repeat the process, but with the same result.
Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The eas team made an emergency hotfix in the 3.7.1 version:
[image: expo-report]

Answer (score 0):

Please do update eas-cli to the most recent version and it will fix the problem.